# How Remove Recycler Separator/divider programmatically or using xml property

Tags: java, android

i am developing a grid cardview using recyclerview and card view in android v25 , facing  behavior of Android recycler view has a divider line that acts as a separator between two rows as shown in the below image

[image: Screen shot from emulator]

I want to remove this line ,i am attaching my layout XMLS and java codes here

**MainActivity.java**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    categoriesAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getAllItemList());

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    // set a GridLayoutManager with default vertical orientation and 3 number of columns
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,  LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

    getAllItemList();
}
```

**main_card_grid.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/country_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/eight"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/country_name"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country_photo"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="groups.wtz.bluewine.com.miyo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="4dp"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which portion of xml is making this underline ,can i update it

Comment: remove recyclerview itemDecorator

Comment: @AswinPAshok thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line making trouble. Because you are adding decoration to your item. This will add divider to your view. Just comment out below line.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,  LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Can you provide your DividerItemDecoration.java class?

Answer (score 0):

You should comment line :

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,  LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

You can refer my code :

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
    listEbook.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    listEbook.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, dpToPx(3), true));
    listEbook.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mAdapter = new EbookAdapter(listEbook, lisBooks, DanhsachEbookActivity.this);
    listEbook.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

with

```
 /**
 * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
 */
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

I hope it can help your problem!